# How can I fix "No directive found for `whereHasConditions`" in Laravel Lighthouse?

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I'm using `"nuwave/lighthouse": "^4.14"` and have this schema.graphql based on [the docs of this feature](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.14/eloquent/complex-where-conditions.html#wherehasconditions):

```
type Query {
    # ...
    postsWithUnseenComments(orderBy: _ @orderBy(columns: ["id", "created_at"], order: ASC), hasComments: _ @whereHasConditions(columns: ["user_id", "seen_at"])): [Post!]! @paginate(defaultCount: 20) @cache
}
```

and I get this error:

```
No directive found for `whereHasConditions` {"exception":"[object] (Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Exceptions\\DirectiveException(code: 0): No directive found for `whereHasConditions` at C:\\code\\myproject\\vendor\
uwave\\lighthouse\\src\\Schema\\Factories\\DirectiveFactory.php:91)
```

I have already tried `php artisan package:discover` from [here](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1057#issuecomment-557788372), but it didn't help.

I know from [the docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.14/custom-directives/getting-started.html#register-directives) that `vendor\nuwave\lighthouse\src\WhereConditions\WhereHasConditionsDirective.php` should automatically be loaded.

@spawnia, thank you so much for your amazing library. I'd appreciate any hints about what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://lighthouse-php.com/4.14/eloquent/complex-where-conditions.html#setup:

**This is an experimental feature and not included in Lighthouse by default.**

Add the service provider to your `config/app.php`

```php
'providers' => [
    \Nuwave\Lighthouse\WhereConditions\WhereConditionsServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Install the dependency [mll-lab/graphql-php-scalars](https://github.com/mll-lab/graphql-php-scalars):

```
composer require mll-lab/graphql-php-scalars
```