# Can’t show my array value in json_encode php undefined

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

This is my cart.php file. array i encoded to json and return to ajax function:

```
 $data = array();

     $data['total'] = '10000';
     $data['quantity'] = '10';

 echo json_encode($data);
```

This my index.php file. I create function ajax to return my array value in cart.php but the value is undefined:

```
 function view()
  {
    $.ajax({  
      url: 'cart.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:{action:'total'},
      datatype:'json',
      success: function (data) {
          
          alert(data.total);
       
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It does not appear that the code you've shown could produce the error you're describing. Something else is going on, which we can't see from this information.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63589662/367456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the "datatype" to "dataType", otherwise the system cannot know that the dataType is in JSON format

```
    $.ajax({  
      url: 'cart.php',
      type:'POST',
      
      // the next line seems unnecessary
      //data:{action:'total'},
      
      dataType:'json',
      success: function (data) {
        
        /// data.total will now be 10000
        alert(data.total);

      }
    });
```

Comment: `datatype:'json'` ensures that jQuery will parse the JSON _before_ it reaches the success callback. This is described in the documentation. Therefore, the OP's issue is not a lack of parsing.

Comment: @ADyson, on closer look, the root of the problem is the spelling of the word dataType (that's why when I previously add the JSON.parse it works). Note: `datatype:'json'` will NOT work, `dataType:'json'` works

Comment: thank you bro , but you'r wrong the data type most be datatype not dataType , but your code run successfuly when data type like this datatype

Comment: Sorry you're right it must be `dataType` for the automatic parsing to work.

Comment: anyway thank you , but don't forget to change it to datatype smaller letter 't' not dataType 'T'

Comment: @BithatCh-Faiq no that is incorrect, check the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . It must have large `T` in `dataType`, otherwise it will not automatically parse the data.

Comment: @ADyson but in my code not working with Large 'T'

Comment: @BithatCh-Faiq then something else must be the problem, have you checked for any JavaScript errors in that situation? Or checked that the raw output from your PHP is definitely valid JSON? "Not working" isn't a useful description of any problem, you need to do some debugging. P.s. why did you accept this answer then if it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @ADyson i accepted because it work with small 't' and i told you it;s working but not with large 'T' anyway thank you

Comment: @BithatCh-Faiq but the answer shows big T, as it should. Your situation sounds odd, something else must be wrong if it "works" with small t.

Comment: If your code fails with capital T (I mean if you use **dataType** it will fail) --- Is it true that you have added the `data=JSON.parse(data)` line in your code which I have suggested in the first version of my answer ? (please note that I have removed this line in my final version of my answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'cart.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data:{action:'some action'},
   dataType:'JSON',
   cache:false,
   success:function(response){
        console.log(response)
   }
})
```

Just return the array as it is from the PHP. Ajax will automatically do the magic.